# How to rename file before upload in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

In form, there are two sections and each section has drop down list and two upload buttons. The drop and file upload is specific to section.User will select the item from drop down and select two file with the help of two upload button from each section. Now I want to rename the file by appending the section id and selected item of drop down. Before upload I will split the file name to get section,selected drop down item and file name and then save data and upload its associated file. Please help how to do it in Angular JS